# Can you explain what the pseudo-code below is trying to do? and what type of code it may be?

Tags: python, arrays

I believe the code is attempting to generate an array and pick the peak number and show the trend but not sure.

```
array[N] # array of N integers, indexed 0 to N-1;

# assume it’s populated with
[1,4,2,-2,-9,10,2,12,2,-4,-4,-4,-4,2,6,7]

peak = array[0]
index = 0
output = [] # array of tuples
For x in 1..N-1
    if (array[x]*array[x-1] > 0)
        if peak < 0 and array[x] < peak
            peak = array[x]
            index = x
        if peak >= 0 and array[x] > peak
            peak = array[x]
            index = x
        else
            output.insert( (index, peak) )
            peak = array[x]
            index = x
        end if
end for
return output
```

Comment: This is not python.

Comment: It might be Visual Basic, it uses "end if".

Comment: But I don't think it uses `for x in 1..N-1`

Comment: `if peak >= 0 and array[x] > peak` should probably be `else if`. Otherwise you don't have enough `end if` statements.

Comment: Let's see what happens when we convert it to python and run it: https://pastebin.com/wFqEJuJw ....

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the code is finding all the (positive peak + dropping positives) and ( negative peak + raising negatives) in an sinusoidal wave along with unchanged values.

If you draw a sine wave from the given array and see the output

```
Output: [(1, 4), (2, 2), (4, -9), (7, 12), (8, 2), (10, -4), (11, -4), (12, -4)]
```

We can see the first peak values(4) followed by dropping positive as peak was positive and then the negative peak(-9) and then next positive peak(12) as there are no negative raising value (you can test by inserting negative number > -9) and then we have 2 which is dropping positive and so on.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Current index and peak values as per pseudo code

```
index = 0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,14,15
peak = 1,4,2,-2,-9,2,12,2,-4,-4,-4,6,7
```

peaks are not making sinusoidal waves as 10 was missing peek, but if we can eliminate the (array[x]*array[x-1] > 0) condition then we can have sinusoidal waves with proper peeks and pseudo-code will make sense with output

```
[(1, 4), (2, 2), (4, -9), (5, 10), (7, 12), (8, 2), (9, -4), (10, -4), (11, -4), (12, -4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_peaks(array):
    N = len(array)
    peak = array[0]
    index = 0
    output = []
    for x in range(1, N):
        if (array[x]*array[x-1] > 0):
            if peak < 0 and array[x] < peak:
                peak = array[x]
                index = x
            if peak >= 0 and array[x] > peak:
                peak = array[x]
                index = x
            else:
                output.append((index, peak))
                peak = array[x]
                index = x
    return output
array=[1,4,2,-2,-9,10,2,12,2,-4,-4,-4,-4,2,6,7]
print(find_peaks(array))
```

it will print the output as [(1, 4), (2, 2), (4, -9), (7, 12), (8, 2), (10, -4), (11, -4), (12, -4), (14, 7)]

Explanation:

Start by initializing the variables peak and index to the first element of the input array and an empty list output to store the tuples of indices and peaks.

Loop through the input array from the second element to the last element.

Check if the product of the current element and the previous element is positive. If not, skip to the next element.

If the product is positive, check whether the current element is greater than or less than the current peak. If the peak is negative and the current element is less than the peak, update the peak and index to the current element and index. If the peak is non-negative and the current element is greater than the peak, update the peak and index to the current element and index.

If the current element is not greater than the peak and the peak is non-negative or not less than the peak and the peak is negative, append a tuple of (index, peak) to the output list, update the peak and index to the current element and index.

After looping through all the elements, return the output list of tuples.

The algorithm essentially looks for "peaks" in the input array, which are defined as pairs of adjacent elements with the same sign (both positive or both negative) and the largest absolute value in that range. The algorithm updates the peak and index whenever it finds a larger peak, and appends the previous peak and index to the output list whenever it encounters a peak that is no longer increasing. The output list thus contains all the peaks and their corresponding indices.